# Question about running input() functions through Terminal on Mac

Tags: python, macos, input, terminal, sublimetext3

I am having trouble with executing input() functions in the Terminal on Mac. I am currently using sublime text editor and running Python version 3.8.3. I am learning Python through a book called Python Crash Course (2nd edition). In chapter 7, one of the notes states "Sublime text and many other editors don't run programs that prompt the user for input. You can use these editors to write programs that prompt for input, but you'll need to run these programs from a terminal. See running Python programs from a terminal on page 12."

On page 12 it discusses how to run Python programs from a terminal. It asks you to open a new terminal window and enter the following commands to run a Python file from a folder thats saved from you computer. In this case it was for a file called hello_world.py

`~$ **cd Desktop/python_work/**`
`~/Desktop/python_work$ **ls**`
`hello_world.py`
`~/Desktop/python_work$ **python hello_world.py**`
`Hello Python world!`

Now here is where my question lies. Every-time I write the first line in this code and press enter, Terminal responds with "Not a directory", even though the Python file I want to run through Terminal is saved on my computer in the Python_work folder. My question is, how can I run a Python file through Terminal?

If you guys need any clarification for anything, please let me know. Any responses will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I understand correctly that you can't even work the first line of your example, ie. directory change?
Do you have a directory `python_work` in `~/Desktop`? E.g. using Finder?
Did you copy the file `hello_world.py` to this folder?
I did not find such a file for this chapter in the book material (on [Github](https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc_2e/tree/master/chapter_07) as link from [book info](https://ehmatthes.github.io/pcc_2e/regular_index/))

Comment: Yes that’s correct I can’t work the first line of the example. The python_work folder is saved within my Desktop folder. Hello_world.py is saved in my python_work folder and I’m not able to run it through the Terminal.

Comment: Your filesystem is case-sensitive, so if your folder is named Python_work you'll need to use a command like `cd Desktop/Python_work`. Also, you can just move one folder at a time. Open a terminal. Then use the command `ls` to see what folders are available. Then use `cd` to navigate into one of these folders. Then use `ls` again to see what's in that folder. If you need to move back up a level in the terminal, you can use `cd ..`.